# getCurrentUser() doesn't give null

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

My Android Project is linked to a Firebase Project. From the app, I have created a new account. Then, from the Firebase console, I have deleted all the accounts present. Then I have restarted the app. I was expected to have null when calling `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` but it doesn't (here the logcat). Why?

[image]

**MyActivity.java**

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    System.out.println(currentUser.getUid());
}
```

**Logcat**

```
11-03 14:48:49.250 25654-25654/com.example.ves.gennaio3 I/System.out: SESbqLQQyDX4qWEaKxBMBukVLrI2
```

Comment: You're likely looking at the locally cached user profile of the last user thar signed in successfully.

Comment: @Eugene I think you should explain better. He seems to ignore that currentUser is token from the cache.